# How can I control the return type based on an argument in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a factory class which will return different classes which all implement a same interface but with different generic. However, my factory class is unable to determine the different generic type used by the interfaces.

For example, I have the following interfaces:

```
interface ICityData<T> {
    data: T
}

interface LondonData {
    a: string,
    b: number
}

interface BerlinData {
    c: string,
    d: string
}

interface NewYorkData {
    a: Record<any, any>,
    e: number
}

interface ICityConcrete<T> {
    retrieve(): T
}
```

I have the follow concrete classes which all implement the `ICityConcrete` interface but uses a different generic type:

```
class LondonConcrete implements ICityConcrete<LondonData> {
    retrieve(): LondonData {
        return {
            a: 'test',
            b: 123
        }
    }
}

class BerlinConcrete implements ICityConcrete<BerlinData> {
    retrieve(): BerlinData {
        return {
            c: 'abc',
            d: 'efg'
        }
    }
}

class NewYorkConcrete implements ICityConcrete<NewYorkData> {
    retrieve(): NewYorkData {
        return {
            a: {
                name: 'test'
            },
            e: 321
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a factory to create those classes depending on the `city` provided as the argument:

```
enum City {
    London,
    NewYork,
    Berlin
}

class MyFactory {
    public static create(city: City): ICityConcrete<TDependsOnCity> {     // TDependsOnCity could be LondonData, BerlinData or NewYorkData depending on the city argument
        switch (city) {
            case City.London:
                return new LondonConcrete();
            case City.Berlin:
                return new BerlinConcrete();
            default:
                return new NewYorkConcrete(); 
        }
    }
}

const myCreatedInstance = MyFactory.create(City.London);
```

Here's the problem, I want `myCreatedInstance` to be of type `ICityConcrete<TDependsOnCity>`. In other words, the type should depend on the `city` provided. If `City.London` was provided in the argument, `myCreatedInstance` should be of type `ICityConcrete<LondonData>`.

I tried to rearrange things in different ways and most of them have `ICityConcrete<any>` no matter what I use as `city`.

[image]

How can I control the return type based on the argument provided in this case?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwglgFwJ5QN4CgpagGQPYgAmBANJtgHLADuAmngE4DWZ2UAQsAwDZwjoBfdOj4IuAMwCGAY2BQAkvGQARSQkkAeACoA%20NOSyE1kgFxQtg4aIky5%20IgVXr9bU1ADOCBnwDmrbABGZuAQAVyWIiBiDFKyHFy8IE6SLtjSZp7eIH4GUIQZXr4R1jG2UFR0jEzJqVhuAErA0oyEGpIgSCRQ7Ug6-ljAwZBhDMVRNnGKiEgwBNIMwGLaehhsC4XAAG7AABQAlGYWQujS3JLu7rgExCCzIPOLcnAQAA7cwBCgCJdTyHcPS3sN2SK1y628W12ByuDiSxlqbCg6zADBACMR2DcAHIxJ4sf0MYEzABGABMAGZcmwhNSIqdzpdODw%20P91k9Xu9PlEfkoZnM2RomYkQQjwXBIfszEK%20DVVoTkaj0YT0lAsZIAtJ8VTCflVcBxD4sdqsDTsEJjvSLuUaPRmKzHlBnm8Pl8edN7UsKrbqsZQWtFhDtpLrZVmLLjUjFii0XLCZizLG44iQJJPmYccA8RHqQS44MoOTScSI6aTXSzlaALJIABiMgQjBQiZeYACvGkHnUCDgHYeal20mmZl50N%20fPuAq0ymAL1AhHcAHlbtMVkmsAB6dfmaezoiL5fIKDNMDcQhQMIw4HGLrSuHORgh701Qgzue%20KAEKAIAAWckHh8kBgfEgL4I3cahEGkb8oB2f8kD2JUMWkc45F5AA6IECBMbN5SjRUQBoS8CA9KEAG4cKwZD3FQ6Y0NvbC1wxBU0QI6h4mZW5%20UefZyMYvJ9UkE8EAYvjsGYqBWMfKoSJ4qAS1yc1hGaEBPCgCAZgWftCHkFT1HuOQAF4oGrOtpAbBgkDQvsxB2dDMJAPYgA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define and use a city type to constructor map:

```
const cityConstructors = {
    [City.London]: LondonConcrete,
    [City.Berlin]: BerlinConcrete,
    [City.NewYork]: NewYorkConcrete,
};

class MyFactory {
    public static create<TCity extends City>(city: TCity): InstanceType<(typeof cityConstructors)[TCity]>
    public static create(city: City) {
        return new cityConstructors[city]();
    }
}

const myCreatedInstance = MyFactory.create(City.London) // LondonConcrete
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwglgFwJ5QN4CgpagGQPYgAmBANJtgHLADuAmngE4DWZ2UAQsAwDZwjoBfdOj4IuAMwCGAY2BQAkvGQARSQkkAeACoA+NOSyE1kgFxQtg4aIky5+IgVXr9bU1ADOCBnwDmrbABGZuAQAVyWIiBiDFKyHFy8IE6SLtjSZp7eIH4GUIQZXr4R1jG2UFR0jEzJqVhuAErA0oyEGpIgSCRQ7Ug6-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)

Comment: And enum can be replaced with `type City = keyof cityConstructors`

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```js
enum City {
    London,
    NewYork,
    Berlin
}

interface ICityData<T> {
    data: T
}

interface LondonData {
    a: string,
    b: number
}

interface BerlinData {
    c: string,
    d: string
}

interface NewYorkData {
    a: Record<any, any>,
    e: number
}

interface ICityConcrete<T> {
    retrieve(): T
}

class LondonConcrete implements ICityConcrete<LondonData> {
    retrieve(): LondonData {
        return {
            a: 'test',
            b: 123
        }
    }
}

class BerlinConcrete implements ICityConcrete<BerlinData> {
    retrieve(): BerlinData {
        return {
            c: 'abc',
            d: 'efg'
        }
    }
}

class NewYorkConcrete implements ICityConcrete<NewYorkData> {
    retrieve(): NewYorkData {
        return {
            a: {
                name: 'test'
            },
            e: 321
        }
    }
}

class MyFactory {
    public static create(city: City.Berlin): ICityConcrete<BerlinData>
    public static create(city: City.London): ICityConcrete<LondonData>
    public static create(city: City): ICityConcrete<NewYorkData>
    public static create(city: City) { 
        switch (city) {
            case City.London:
                return new LondonConcrete();
            case City.Berlin:
                return new BerlinConcrete();
            default:
                return new NewYorkConcrete(); 
        }
    }
}

const myCreatedInstance = MyFactory.create(City.London) //  ICityConcrete<LondonData>
const myCreatedInstance2 = MyFactory.create(City.Berlin) //  ICityConcrete<BerlinData>
const myCreatedInstance3 = MyFactory.create(City.NewYork) //  ICityConcrete<NewYorkData>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwglgFwJ5QN4CgpagGQPYgAmBANJtgHLADuAmngE4DWZ2UAQsAwDZwjoBfdOj4IuAMwCGAY2BQAkvGQARSQkkAeACoA%20NOSyE1kgFxQtg4aIky5%20IgVXr9bU1ADOCBnwDmrbABGZuAQAVyWIiBiDFKyHFy8IE6SLtjSZp7eIH4GUIQZXr4R1jG2UFR0jEzJqVhuAErA0oyEGpIgSCRQ7Ug6-ljAwZBhDMVRNnGKiEgwBNIMwGLaehhsC4XAAG7AABQAlGYWQujS3JLu7rgExCCzIPOLcnAQAA7cwBCgCJdTyHcPS3sN2SK1y628W12ByuDiSxlqbCg6zADBACMR2DcAHIxJ4sf0MYEzABGABMAGZcmwhNSIqdzpdODw%20P91k9Xu9PlEfkoZnM2RomYkQQjwXBIfszEK%20DVVoTkaj0YT0lAsZIAtJ8VTCflVcBxD4sdqsDTsEJjvSLuUaPRmKzHlBnm8Pl8edN7UsKrbqsZQWtFhDtpLrZVmLLjUjFii0XLCZizLG44iQJJPmYccA8RHqQS44MoOTScSI6aTXSzlaALJIABiMgQjBQiZeYACvGkHnUCDgHYeal20mmZl5ADppSBob8%20fcBeOQbkW22e521Mu%202IdoPkMPpiOgQRJ7yPcANPu4eodAvW%202V93ewt%205uh7Bpof3fzHhovVV52xFzfPFXe9gEfLckB3ZA9jQKAI3cahEGkAALKAn0gpUMWkc45FHM8TGzeUo0VEAaBhG5j32ABufCsEw9xsN3cc8KTAiEGjKBiOoeJmVuD8Nz2KjmMMfVJDAbgECYwT-VYoiSO-O1eKhCiYLjUsoHNYRmhATwoAgGYHzEQh5C09R7jkABeKBqzraQGwYJAR3XXYcOuA8oAAejcrAp2PU8XPPSRL007TdJgfTgEM4z2lkUkoAsqz60bBywp2UdxygjyvKPBTBQSGVfROAhgr0kCDKMwDTPJWLLNrBK7KSkqnN3OSmHSzyFCymdP2akEgA)